# Facebook SDK for iOS Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I need help adding this code from Facebook to enable advertiser tracking. Here is a link to the description. I do not know where to place the code in Xcode’s source code. Can someone help me?

The link below has the code.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/setting-up/platform-setup/ios/SKAdNetwork
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0GKV.png)

Comment: Instead of linking to an image or elsewhere, please paste the relevant code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The guide that you linked says:

> Add the following SKAdNetwork IDs to your Xcode project’s `Info.plist`

So, add them! Note that the example is in `XML` form, but the `Info.plist` is displayed visually. You need to Right-Click -> <kbd>Open As</kbd> -> <kbd>Source Code</kbd>.

[image: Right-Click Info.plist -> Open As -> Source Code]

Then just paste them in.

```
<key>SKAdNetworkItems</key> /// make sure you also add this line
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
        <string>v9wttpbfk9.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
        <string>n38lu8286q.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The example doesn't include `<key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>`, but you need to add this (check out the [For more information section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/setting-up/platform-setup/ios/SKAdNetwork#:%7E:text=for%20more%20information%2C%20see%20the%20configure%20a%20source%20app%20section%20of%20the%20configuring%20the%20participating%20apps%20topic%20in%20the%20apple%20storekit%20documentation.))

[image: Paste in the above code at the bottom of the Info.plist XML, before the ending "dict" tag]